# How can I solve this artifact (or bad shading) caused by this tri-gon?

Tags: modeling, vertices, subdivision-surface, topology, artifacts

This might be a stupid question as there's a chance that without the file it's not possible to figure out how to solve this, but:

I am modeling a Daihatsu Midget and I can't figure out how to replace this tri-gon with a quad-gon to solve this shading issue:

[image]

[image]

As you can see I am using Subdivision with Levels Viewport set to 3. Creases don't really help but I want the wheel arches to stay sharp, removing the Vertex Crease just makes it look even worse.

Do you have any idea how to remove that bad shading (or turn the tri-gon into a quad-gon) to get this look nice and flat?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hello could you please share this part of your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, yes I uploaded it to Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kg5v5gwqmV3Wer6hOtRRr2Zv108WIDJe/view?usp=sharing
Note that it has another similar artifact on the other side of the wheel arch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this topology (I've removed all *Mark Sharp* and so on):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you this will be great :)